# Combine 2 line wires and add ground wires

Tags: electrical

I'm looking to install `Decora Single Pole In-Wall Combination Occupancy Sensor with Fan Switch`. My current switch is like below, there is no ground but I can see holes with `GRD` in the back and some screws sticking out.

The [instruction](https://images.thdstatic.com/catalog/pdfImages/dd/dd142112-cdde-4275-b3b0-e921b0e01fb6.pdf) for no neutral only has 1 wire for LINE so my questions are:

1. To add Ground, do I connect a bare metal wire to one of the screws or connect it somehow to the hole in the back that has the word `GRD` next to it?
2. Is it safe to combine the 2 line wires coming out from the box to the 1 LINE wire from the switch? I assume line wires are the ones that have electricity even with the switch off? (I use [this](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Klein-Tools-Non-Contact-Voltage-Tester-Pen-50-1000V-AC-NCVT1PR/317460355) for testing)
   [image]
   [image]

EDIT 1: House was built in the 1950s. This is 2 different switches that share the same box, 1 for the fan and 1 for the bathroom light. There is only 1 switch at the circuit board that control them (and also an outlet). I don't really need the Decora. I'm only looking for an in-wall timer that can share the box with a switch
[image]

Comment: To confirm, there are two black and two white wires coming into the box? It doesn't look like there is a ground wire, but perhaps the box is grounded via a metal conduit. You could check if the box is grounded by carefully following the procedure at this link: https://decorasmartsupport.leviton.com/hc/en-us/articles/4595240060955-How-Do-I-Know-If-I-Have-An-Earth-Ground

Answer (score 1):

It seems odd that you would have 2 cables going to the same place and all 4 wires attached to the same switch.

With the 2 cables being on the same circuit, there's no concern about shorting hot wires from separate circuits.

However, there is a nuance in NEC 310.10 about not running parallel hot wires that are "joined at both ends".  Because of this rule, you still need 2 separate switches.  The combination sensor switch with its combined hot wire isn't going to comply with that rule.

Also the hot wires must be the cables' white wires, and they have to be identified with electrical tape.

Today's electrical code no longer allows unidentified white wires attached to switches.  To do this correctly, you'll need to wrap part of those wires with electrical tape, both inside this box as well as inside the fan box and the light box.  The tape must not be white or green or gray.  Red is my favorite but black is more common and sometimes cheaper.  The white wires must act as "the supply to the switch", which means line hot wires.  If it was set up with the black wires being hot, you'll have to rearrange some things in the fan box and the light box too.

Don't touch those screws in the switch box.  They are holding the box together.  One of those holes in the back should be threaded.  If so, you can get something as simple as a pre-made pigtail with a green screw.  Or you can buy the green or bare wire and a box of green screws.

Comment: Thanks. I updated the post with more information: House was built in the 1950s. This is 2 different switches that share the same box, 1 for the fan and 1 for the bathroom light. There is only 1 switch at the circuit board that controls them (and also an outlet). I don't really need the Decora. I'm only looking for an in-wall timer, mechanical is fine, that also come with a light switch

Comment: @Motoko Thanks.  Answer updated.

Comment: Actually, no it isn't OK to splice the two hots together due to the parallel wire rules in the NEC (300.3(B)/310.10(H))

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Getting technical now.  But I get it.  Answer reverted.

Comment: Thanks. So what's the technical term for this kind of switches that have 2 independent switches fit into 1 box? I searched for "duplex switch and timer" but even this Lutron switch still use 3 wires only, not 2 independent switches https://www.homedepot.com/p/Lutron-Maestro-LED-Dual-Dimmer-and-Timer-Switch-75-Watt-LED-Bulbs-2-5-Amp-Fans-Single-Pole-White-MACL-L3T251-WH-MACL-L3T251-WH/328685391